# Error while installing simplejson via pip (OS X Yosemite)

Tags: python, macos, pip, simplejson

As I was trying to install the package soundcloud via pip, I got the warning :

```
Error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson': P error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson': Permission denied
```

So, I recursively set the folder permissions to 777 with my file manager.

I ran pip install soundcloud again. Got the warning:

```
simplejson/_speedups.c:2640:42: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            int int_as_string_bitcount_val = PyLong_AsLong(int_as_string_bitcount);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/simplejson/_speedups.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/simplejson/_speedups.so
```

While according to pip list soundcloud and its dependencies (simplejson 3.6.5) are installed, I wanted to know if I had to do something about this warning and if the answer to thiis question is "yes" then "what".

Comment: The answer is no....is just a warning related to a conversion in speedups.c, not a soundcloud related issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error isn't going to effect you too much unless you are doing super precise math, i.e. Landing on moon, running a stock exchange, etc.

Also in the future use sudo pip, it will ask for your password, then run pip as "root". Similar to "run as administrator" in windows. Also you won't go blowing away your permission settings.

Comment: (About "sudo pip") I red it was not the most secure way to do it (could be harmful). On the same stackoverflow thread, there was a solution I founded quicker and not potentially harmful. This is the one used... that led me to this warning.

Comment: you should be using a virtenv and/or installing to your user path. See: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668 , https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/. I was just narrowly answering the question at hand ;) There are a lot about there on best practices, but I was trying to no be too opionionated. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251108/what-is-too-opinionated-about-this-question